# Phonemic vs. phonetic notation: /m/ in mass vs. symphony

Tags: phonetics, phonology

Dictionaries such as [ldoceonline.com](https://ldoceonline.com) use a phonemic notation for the two words spelled: *mass* and *symphony*, i.e. /mæs/ vs  /ˈsɪmfəni/

But this is hardly the whole story: to me (a non-native) the two consonants are not the same (the two words are common in a lot of languages). How would you describe them using a true phonetic notation (the [] one)?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but how would you describe the way that the two consonants are different to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [ˈsɪɱ.fə.ni] according to:

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/symphony
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labiodental_nasal#occurance

The ɱ character represents the voiced labiodental nasal.

From that Wikipedia article linked above:

> The labiodental pronunciation of [ɱ] is very similar to that of the bilabial nasal [m], but instead of the lips touching each other, the lower lip touches the upper teeth
>
> Although commonly appearing in languages, it is overwhelmingly an allophone restricted to a position before the labiodental consonants [f] and [v]